# Error: "Load failed" trying to upload images to supabase

Tags: reactjs, next.js, supabase, supabase-js

In my next.js app I am trying to upload image from form. But I keep getting an error:
`[Error] Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: Load failed` 
And the file doesn't upload to supabase.

I checked the image variable via console, it is a File object. Here is how I do it, I followed the tutorial in documentation:

```
import * as Form from "@radix-ui/react-form";
import { createClient } from "@supabase/supabase-js";

const supabase = createClient(
  "url",
  "api-key",
);

export default function Warehouses() {

  async function uploadImage(e) {
    const image = e.files[0];

    const { data, error } = await supabase.storage
      .from("images")
      .upload("/", image);

    if (data) {
      console.log(data);
    } else {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    uploadImage(event.target.images);
  };

  return (
    <div>
        <Form.Root className="FormRoot" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          <Form.Field className="FormField" name="images">
            <div
              style={{
                display: "flex",
                alignItems: "baseline",
                justifyContent: "space-between",
              }}
            >
              <Form.Label className="FormLabel">
                Upload Images
              </Form.Label>
            </div>
            <Form.Control asChild>
              <input
                type="file"
                id="images"
                name="images"
                multiple
              />
            </Form.Control>
          </Form.Field>

          <Form.Submit asChild>
            <Button>Create</Button>
          </Form.Submit>
        </Form.Root>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I will appreciate any help!

**UPDATE**

I get this error in Safari browser also:

```
[Error] Fetch API cannot load https://my-url/storage/v1/object/images/2 due to access control checks.
```

Here is what I get from console.log(image) inside uploadImage():
[image: image variable]

I also tried to check the connection to supabase with this code:

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const buckets = await supabase.storage.listBuckets();
  console.log(buckets);
  
  return {
    props: {
      bucketList: buckets,
    },
  };
}
```

But I get this in the console: ``` { data: [], error: null } ``

Below are the policies to my supabase bucket "images":

[image]

Here is the first (select) policy edit window:
[image]

And the insert policy:
[image]

Here is how the policies were added to my bucket:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The line `.upload("/", files)`, shouldn't it be `.upload("/", e.files)` ?

Comment: @c_thane you are right, there was a typo in my question, I edited it. I get the error with .upload(“/“, image)

Comment: What exactly do you get when you do `console.log(image)` inside `uploadImage()` method?

Comment: @dshukertjr I added this to my question. I also added some new information: it seems that for some reason I can't access my supabase buckets. Although there is an "images" bucket created with the policies that any anon user can access it.

Comment: @ДаниэльСеидов Could you also share all of your policies in Supabase storage?

Comment: @dshukertjr yes, I'll add them. I basically just used policies -> get started quickly -> Allow access to JPG images in a public folder to anonymous users

Comment: @ДаниэльСеидов For the `upload()` method, the insert policy needs to pass. Could I see the insert policy for the images bucket? Also, is the user signed in when you perform the upload?

Comment: @dshukertjr I added the insert policy. I don't have authentication in my app for now, is it obligatory to have it to store images in bucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not uploading the file in a way that passes the insert policy you have in place.

The issue is that you have the `storage.foldername(name)[1] = 'public'`, but you are not uploading the image in a `public` folder. For this poilcy to pass, you need to upload the image into `/public` path instead of `/`. I assume what you meant here is that you are uploading an image to a public bucket, but that is different from uploading to a public path. I think you can remove the `storage.foldername(name)[1] = 'public'` statement.

Also, there are other things you can remove as well. First, we recently added a feature to restrict the meme types of the object being uploaded to a bucket. You can set it like this to only accept jpg.

[image: restrict meme types]

About the role, the correct way to specify which role you want the policy to be applied to is to select the `target roles` from the policy editor. You can set this to `anon` to target anon users.

With all of that, you should be left with the following simple policy for what you want to do.

[image: insert policy]

Note that having users sign in to your app is not essential, but might be something to consider before you start promoting your app, because otherwise anyone can upload images to your bucket without any restrictions.

Comment: Thank for such a detailed response and for the additional advices! I will add authentication in future. I deleted all the policies and added two for select and for insert as you wrote. Unfortunately, the issue stays. I still get "TypeError: Load Failed". Is it something with my policies or could there be some else reasons?

Comment: I also tried adding this code inside uploadImage() to check if I can get access my buckets: 

    ```const abc = await supabase.storage.listBuckets();
    console.log(abc);```

    in console I get: ```{data: [], error: StorageUnknownError: Load Failed}```

Comment: It finally worked after I provided the name of the image! Thanks a lot for your help, the problem was in policies. So now it is something like this:  ```const { data } = await supabase.storage.from("images").upload(`/${filePath}/${image.name}`, image);```

Comment: @ДаниэльСеидов Oh yeah, missed that part! Also, the reason why you are not getting any buckets from `listBuckets()` is because you don't have any policies set on buckets. You typically don't want to expose bucket information publicly, so I suggest to keep not having any policies for the buckets though.